# Enviar variable de Scriptlet a Servlet

Tags: java, netbeans, servlets

Buenas noches gente de Stack Overflown, escribo pq tengo un problema y quisiera ver si me podrian ayudar

Un profesor nos mando un ejercicio en donde se debe crear un carro de compras y al presionar el boton submit se debe mostrar los resultados en un Servlet, mi problema es que al enviar el resultado al servlet no me muestra la cantidad ni el total de producto que he escogido, solo me muestra el valor inicial que le asigne a la variable

Adjunto el Scriptlet y Servlet

SCRIPTLET

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index2
    Created on : 12-04-2018, 10:21:25
    Author     : alumnos09
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Kwik E Mart</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <header>

            <h3>Bienvenidos a Kwik E Mart</h3>

        </header>

        <main>

            <form action="Kwik_E_Mart" method="post">

                Escoja sus productos a llevar:

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Batidos"> Batidos - 1000 $
                <input type="number" name="valor1" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Pan"> Pan - 200 $
                <input type="number" name="valor2" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Huevos"> Huevos - 500 $
                <input type="number" name="valor3" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Leche"> Leche - 3000 $
                <input type="number" name="valor4" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Helado"> Helado - 2500 $
                <input type="number" name="valor5" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Gomitas"> Gomitas - 1200 $
                <input type="number" name="valor6" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Harina"> Harina - 550 $
                <input type="number" name="valor7" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Azucar"> Azucar -475 $
                <input type="number" name="valor8" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Sal"> Sal - 300 $
                <input type="number" name="valor9" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Rosquillas"> Rosquillas - 650 $
                <input type="number" name="valor10" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Perro Caliente"> Perro Caliente - 870 $
                <input type="number" name="valor11" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Papas Fritas"> Papas Fritas - 1000 $
                <input type="number" name="valor12" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Tabaco"> Tabaco - 630 $
                <input type="number" name="valor13" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Agua"> Agua - 990 $
                <input type="number" name="valor14" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <input type="checkbox" name="producto" value="Refresco"> Refresco - 1490 $
                <input type="number" name="valor15" placeholder="Cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="true">

                <br/>
                <br/>

                Escoja su metodo de pago:

                <input type="radio" name="pago" value="Efectivo" checked> Efectivo
                <input type="radio" name="pago" value="Tarjeta de Debito o Credito"> Tarjeta de Debito o Credito
                <input type="radio" name="pago" value="APU"> Tarjeta APU´s

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <% session.setAttribute("precio",Integer.valueOf(cantidad_total)); %>

                <input type="submit" value="Terminar Compra">

            </form>

            <% int cantidad_total = 0; int valor = 0; int cantidad_llevar = 0; int productos_llevar = 0; %>

            <% String productos[] = request.getParameterValues("producto"); %>

            <% if (productos != null) { %>

                <% for (int i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) { %>

                    <% if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Batidos")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor1") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor1")); %>

                            <% valor = 1000 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Pan")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor2") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor2")); %>

                            <% valor = 200 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Huevos")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor3") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor3")); %>

                            <% valor = 500 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Leche")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor4") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor4")); %>

                            <% valor = 3000 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Helado")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor5") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor5")); %>

                            <% valor = 2500 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Gomitas")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor6") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor6")); %>

                            <% valor = 1200 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Harina")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor7") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor7")); %>

                            <% valor = 550 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Azucar")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor8") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor8")); %>

                            <% valor = 475 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Sal")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor9") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor9")); %>

                            <% valor = 300 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Rosquillas")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor10") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor10")); %>

                            <% valor = 650 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Perro Caliente")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor11") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor11")); %>

                            <% valor = 870 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Papas Fritas")) { %>

                       <% if (request.getParameter("valor12") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor12")); %>

                            <% valor = 1000 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Tabaco")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor13") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor13")); %>

                            <% valor = 630 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Agua")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor14") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor14")); %>

                            <% valor = 990 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% } else if (productos[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Refresco")) { %>

                        <% if (request.getParameter("valor15") != null) { %>

                            <% cantidad_llevar = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor15")); %>

                            <% valor = 1490 * cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% productos_llevar = productos_llevar + cantidad_llevar; %>

                            <% cantidad_total = cantidad_total + valor; %>

                        <% }; %>

                    <% }; %>

                <% }; %>

            <% }; %>

        </main>

    </body>

</html>
```

SERVLET

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import static org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include;

/**
 *
 * @author alumnos09
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Kwik_E_Mart"})
public class Kwik_E_Mart extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Kwik_E_Mart</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            String precio = (String) (session.getAttribute("precio"));

            if (request.getParameter("pago").equalsIgnoreCase("efectivo")) {

                out.println("El metodo de pago seleccionado fue: Efectivo");
                out.println("No tiene descuento por este metodo de pago");

                response.getWriter().print("<p> La variable vale " + precio + "</p>");

            } else if (request.getParameter("pago").equalsIgnoreCase("tarjeta de debito o credito")) {

                out.println("El metodo de pago seleccionado fue: Tarjeta de Debito o Credito");
                out.println("No tiene descuento por este metodo de pago");

            } else if (request.getParameter("pago").equalsIgnoreCase("apu")) {

                out.println("El metodo de pago seleccionado fue: Tarjeta APU´s");
                out.println("Felicidades, podra obtener un descutno por una compra mayor a 5 productos.");

            };

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

El valor que deseo llevar al Servlet es el que dice cantidad_total

El ejercicio pide que las formulas sean realizadas en Scriptlet y los resultados sean mostrados en Servlet, soy un novato en este tema.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias por su atencion.

Answer (score 1):

Añade un `input` al formulario de tipo `hidden`, y asigna ahí el valor.
De esta manera, cuando hagas submit del formulario al servlet, podrás acceder al valor a través de la request.

Así, en tu html y después de calcular el valor de `cantidad_total`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=cantidad_total%>" name="sumaCantidadTotal"/>
```

Debes añadir esto dentro del `<form>`, por lo tanto también deberías añadir la parte del cálculo de cantidad_total dentro de este.

Hecho eso, y ya en tu servlet, en el `doPost`:

```
int cantidadTotal = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sumaCantidadTotal"));
```

Comment: Hola buenas, hice lo que me dijiste pero aun asi me envia valor 0 cuando hago el submit y me carga el servlet.

Comment: Cambia el input a text en vez de hidden, y válida así que el valor se carga correctamente antes de hacer el submit. Por ver dónde está el error.